# How to clear data in NgRx store after fetch in reducer

Tags: angular, ngrx, store

My app is using angular with ngrx store.
I am trying to clear the data from stores, once the "fetch" event is called. I am guessing i can do that in the reducer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply create another rule in the reducer with "on ()" which is performed on the action you want

```
const userReducer = createReducer(
     initialState,
     on(yourAction, (state) => ({ user:null }))
);
```

Comment: in the reducer function?

Comment: and how do i clear the data? state = undefined?

Comment: yes in the reducer function. You can use null in each property of the state, becouse the state has an initial state, I think you can't cancel each propreties, just set null (property:null)

Comment: like this? ``` export function reducer(
  state: state_name | undefined,
  action: Action
) {
  if (action.type === 'ACTON_TYPE') {
    state = undefined;
  }
  return reducer(state, action);
}
```

Comment: I'm glad I helped you!